# Tool for analyzing and graphing dependency between Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, uml, dependency-management

Is there a program/tool that can generate function dependency graph for javascripts? Basically, the input should be a folder of javascript files, then the output is a nice graph that show all the relations between each function. It'll be better if I can interact with the graph, also.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On windows and Visual Studio you can look at JSAnalyse: http://jsanalyse.codeplex.com/

I haven't tried it, but from the description, it parse the JavaScript files and creates a dependency tree of the different files based on the static references between them.

### The project

> JSAnalyse is a tool to analyze the dependencies between JavaScript
>   files and keep them under control. It helps to visualize and handle
>   static references between JavaScript files in order to ensure the
>   defined client-side architecture.
>
> In the last couple years the amount of JavaScript lines in web
>   applications has been dramatically increased. A lot of new client-side
>   frameworks (like JQuery, Knockout, etc...) have aroused, but the tools
>   for developing JavaScript just got slightly better. For instance, the
>   Visual Studio 2010 has improved the IntelliSense. But for a
>   well-designed application, not only the server-side code is relevant
>   anymore. It is also very important to have a good architecture for the
>   client-side code and to keep it in a healthy and good state during the
>   whole application lifecycle. That is exactly when JSAnalyse comes into
>   play. It enables not just the possibility to analyze the existing
>   JavaScript dependencies but also to constrain them. The allowed
>   dependencies can be either configured via XML or by using the great
>   Visual Studio 2010 Architecture features. JSAnalyse provides an
>   extension for the Visual Studio Layer Diagram to validate and control
>   also dependencies between JavaScript files. This can be integrated
>   into the build and with the Gated Check-in feature it is not even
>   possible to check-in source code which does not fulfill the JavaScript
>   architectural rules.

Comment: Thanks. This one I tried but didn't work. I followed the instruction and dragged in all the javascript files but it didn't create any dependency info.

Comment: I tried a sample projet and works with it; can you give me a sample dependency files?